# Using wildcard with symlink command creates wrong links when run from Jenkins

Tags: nginx, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I can't wrap my head around this issue. I run symlink command over SSH from my Jenkins job. In my Jenkins pipeline I have these 2 steps (among others).

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available"
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f"
```

Here's the relevant part of the log:

```
[Pipeline] sh
[my_job] Running shell script
+ ssh ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX sudo ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Sep 18 17:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root   4096 Aug 30 12:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  467 Sep 18 17:27 my-nginx-config
[Pipeline] sh
[my_job] Running shell script
+ ssh ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/jenkins /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f
'/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default' -> '/etc/nginx/sites-available/default'
'/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jenkins' -> '/etc/nginx/sites-available/jenkins'
```

Symlinks are created on my remote host but instead of the `my-nginx-config` symlink, the `default` and `jenkins` files (which are on my jenkins host at `/etc/nginx/sites-available`) are symlinked.

If I don't use wildcard and run this, it works as expected:

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available"
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-nginx-conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes remote ssh commands (and locations for scp) need extra escaping.  I know you've already quoted your query, but you may need one additional level of escapes (and because the escape would be interpreted by your double-quotes rather than being passed to the SSH command, you need one more.

Try double-escaping that wildcard:

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available"
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/\\* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f"
```

You can also combine those into one SSH call:

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} sudo ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available; sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/\\* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f"
```

I'm not a Jenkins expert.  If this doesn't work, I'd try yet another pair of escapes, changing your original `…/sites-available/*` to `…/sites-available/\\\\*`

Comment: Thanks, escaping with double backslash works! I now also tried quoting the whole remote command (see my own answer) and that works too.

Answer (score 1):

The remote commands need to be quoted (although most of them work without quotes):

```
sh "ssh ubuntu@${host} 'sudo ln -sv /etc/nginx/sites-available/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -f'"
```

Comment: Yeah, the extra single quote prevents interpreting the `*` locally.  I wasn't sure how Jenkins handled nesting, so I went with the uglier yet (mildly) safer escape-based solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46285671/519360).